# How to describe this event log in formal BNF?

Tags: grammar, bnf, ebnf, gocc

I have a very simple event log format, just I'm having difficulties describing it in BNF (for [`gocc`](https://github.com/goccmack/gocc/blob/master/doc/gocc_user_guide.pdf) ).

Here is my simple event log format:

```
timestamp nested-event-A Running
timestamp Start of nested-event-B
timestamp Start unested-event-C
timestamp End unested-event-C
timestamp Start unested-event-D
timestamp End unested-event-D
timestamp Start unested-event-E
timestamp End unested-event-E
. . .
timestamp End of nested-event-B 
timestamp nested-event-A completed
```

Say the grammar begins with `EventLog`, and I'm even having difficulties starting the first BNF.

Shall I start with

```
EventLog ::= nested-event | unested-event
```

Or,

Shall I start with

```
EventLog ::= nested-event

nested-event ::= nested-event-start unested-event+ nested-event-end
```

What would you think the best way to describe it?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the productions of EventLog, your choice must depend on the knowledge whether if the starting event is always a nested one or can be unested.
If your log consist with many logs of any kind of events, go with:

You can go with:

```
EventLog ::= event*
event ::= nested-event | unested-event
nested-event ::= nested-event-start unested-event+ nested-event-end
...
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the full [`gocc`](https://github.com/goccmack/gocc/blob/master/doc/gocc_user_guide.pdf) BNF, proven to be tested and working:

```
/* Lexical part */

_digit : '0'-'9' ;

_jobLog     : 'M'  'y'  'J'  'o'  'b' ;

_lineend : [ '\r' ] '\n' ;

timestamp
  : _digit _digit _digit _digit '-' _digit _digit '-' _digit _digit
    ' ' _digit _digit ':' _digit _digit ':' _digit _digit '.' { _digit } ' '
  ;

jobLogStart     : _jobLog' '  'R'  'u'  'n'  'n'  'i'  'n'  'g'  ' '  'j'  'o'  'b' _lineend ;
processLogStart : 'S'  't'  'a'  'r'  't'  ' '  'o'  'f'  ' ' { . } _lineend;
taskLogStart    : 'S'  't'  'a'  'r'  't'  ' ' { . } _lineend;
taskLogEnd  : 'E'  'n'  'd'  ' ' { . } _lineend;
processLogEnd   : 'E'  'n'  'd'  ' '  'o'  'f'  ' ' { . } _lineend;
jobLogEnd       : _jobLog ' '  'J'  'o'  'b'  ' '  'c'  'o'  'm'  'p'  'l'  'e'  't'  'e'  'd' _lineend ;


/* Syntax part */

EventLog
  : JobLog
  ;

JobLog
  : JobLogStart ProcessLog JobLogEnd
  ;

ProcessLog
  : ProcessLogStart TaskLog ProcessLogEnd
  ;

TaskLog
  : TaskLogStart TaskLogEnd
  | TaskLog
    TaskLogStart TaskLogEnd
  ;

TaskLogStart : timestamp taskLogStart ;
TaskLogEnd   : timestamp  taskLogEnd  ;

ProcessLogStart : timestamp processLogStart ;
ProcessLogEnd   : timestamp  processLogEnd  ;

JobLogStart : timestamp jobLogStart ;
JobLogEnd   : timestamp  jobLogEnd  ;
```

For the completeness, here is the sample data that tested fine with above syntax:

```
2022-01-18 10:19:41.6007 MyJob Running job
2022-01-18 10:21:24.8027 Start of The Processing 1/18/2022
2022-01-18 10:21:24.8027 Start unested event C
2022-01-18 10:21:24.8027 End unested event C
2022-01-18 10:21:24.8199 Start unested event D with more words
2022-01-18 10:33:21.9885 End unested event D with more words
2022-01-18 10:33:21.9885 Start unested event E with different words
2022-01-18 10:33:21.9885 End unested event E with different words
2022-01-18 10:33:23.9087 Start unested event F with different words
2022-01-18 10:33:40.8774 End unested event F with different words
2022-01-18 10:33:40.8774 Start ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.4284 End ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.4445 Start ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.5237 End ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.5237 Start ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.6597 End ...
2022-01-18 10:35:13.6597 Start ...
2022-01-18 10:36:24.4468 End ...
2022-01-18 10:36:24.4468 Start ...
2022-01-18 10:36:24.4554 End ...
2022-01-18 10:36:24.7238 End of The Processing 1/18/2022
2022-01-18 10:36:24.9746 MyJob Job completed
```