# Gocc to ignore things in lexical parser

Tags: go, parsing, ebnf, gocc

Is there ways to tell [`gocc`](https://github.com/goccmack/gocc/blob/master/doc/gocc_user_guide.pdf) to ignore things in lexical parser? E.g., for

`2022-01-18 11:33:21.9885 [21] These are strings that I need to egnore, until - MYKW - Start Active One: 1/18/2022 11:33:21 AM`

I want to tell `gocc` to ignore from `[21]` all the way to `until`. Here is what I've been trying:

```
/* Lexical part */

_letter : 'A'-'Z' | 'a'-'z' | '_' ;
_digit : '0'-'9' ;

_timestamp1 : _digit | ' ' | ':' | '-' | '.' ;
_timestamp2 : _digit | ' ' | ':' | '/' | 'A' | 'P' | 'M' ;

_ignore :  '['  { . } ' '  '-'  ' '  'M'  'Y'  'K'  'W'  ' '  '-'  ' ' ;

_lineend : [ '\r' ] '\n' ;


timestamp       : _timestamp1 { _timestamp1 } _ignore ;
taskLogStart    : 'S'  't'  'a'  'r'  't'  ' ' ;
jobName     : { . } _timestamp2 { _timestamp2 } _lineend ;


/* Syntax part */
Log
 : timestamp taskLogStart jobName ;
```

However, the parser failed at:

```
error: expected timestamp; got: unknown/invalid token "2022-01-18 11:33:21.9885 [21] T"
```

The reason I think it should be working is that, the following ignore rule works perfectly fine for white spaces:

```
!lineComment  : '/' '/' { . } '\n' ;
!blockComment : '/' '*' { . | '*' } '*' '/' ;
```

and I'm just applying the above rule into my normal text parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way --

The EBNF looks very much like regular expressions but it does not work like regular expression at all -- what I mean is,

The line,

`2022-01-18 11:33:21.9885 [21] These are strings that I need to ignore, until - MYKW - Start Active One: 1/18/2022 11:33:21 AM`

If to match with regular expression, it can simply be:

`([0-9.: -]+).*? - MYKW - Start ([^:]+):.*$`

However, that cannot be directly translate into EBNF definition just like that, because the regular expression relies on the context in between each elements to ping point a match (e.g., the `.*?` matching rule is a local rule that only works based on the context it is in), however, `gocc` is a LR parser, which is a context-free grammar!!!

Basically a context-free grammar means, each time it is trying to do a `.*` match to all existing lexical symbols (i.e., each lexical symbol can be considered a global rule that is not affected by the context it is in). I cannot quite describe it but there is no previous context (or the symbol following it) involved in next match. That's the reason why the OP fails.

For a real sample of how the '`{.}`' can be used, see

[How to describe this event log in formal BNF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760533/)